# GenerationType.SEQUENCE does not generate sequence in hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, sql-server-2012, sequence

This is my entity file :-

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "tbl_article_function_instruction_status")
@XmlRootElement

public class ArticleFonctionInstructionStatuts extends BaseEntity implements Serializable
{
    private static final long                                   serialVersionUID    = 1L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "AFIS_Sequence")
    @SequenceGenerator(allocationSize = 5000, name="AFIS_Sequence", sequenceName="AFIS_Sequence")
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @Column(name = "art_fun_ins_status_id")
    private Integer                                             afiStaIndex;

    @Basic(optional = false)
    @Column(name = "art_fun_ins_status_date")
    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    private Date                                                afiStaDate;

}
```

I have tried `GenerationType.SEQUENCE` & `GenerationType.AUTO`.
But in case of `GenerationType.SEQUENCE`, it gives me an error :-

> Caused by: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit: default] Unable to build Hibernate SessionFactory
>       at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.persistenceException(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:1239)
>       at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.access$600(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:120)
>       at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl$4.perform(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:855)
>       at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl$4.perform(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:845)
>       at org.hibernate.boot.registry.classloading.internal.ClassLoaderServiceImpl.withTccl(ClassLoaderServiceImpl.java:398)
>       at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:844)
>       at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.java:60)
>       at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.createNativeEntityManagerFactory(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:343)
>       at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:318)
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1627)
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1564)
>       ... 42 more
>   Caused by: org.hibernate.MappingException: Could not instantiate id generator [entity-name=com.alstom.autofie.entity.ArticleFonctionInstructionStatuts]
>       at org.hibernate.id.factory.internal.DefaultIdentifierGeneratorFactory.createIdentifierGenerator(DefaultIdentifierGeneratorFactory.java:123)
>       at org.hibernate.mapping.SimpleValue.createIdentifierGenerator(SimpleValue.java:213)
>       at org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.(SessionFactoryImpl.java:323)
>       at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1859)
>       at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl$4.perform(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:852)
>       ... 50 more
>   Caused by: org.hibernate.MappingException: com.alstom.autofie2.dao.CustomSQLDialect does not support sequences
>       at org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect.getSequenceNextValString(Dialect.java:882)
>       at org.hibernate.id.SequenceGenerator.configure(SequenceGenerator.java:110)
>       at org.hibernate.id.SequenceHiLoGenerator.configure(SequenceHiLoGenerator.java:55)
>       at org.hibernate.id.factory.internal.DefaultIdentifierGeneratorFactory.createIdentifierGenerator(DefaultIdentifierGeneratorFactory.java:117)
>       ... 54 more

Here CustomSQLDialect is a class which extends SQLServerDialect.

In case of `GenerationType.AUTO`, it gives me an error while inserting multiple records because it generates same key all the time, not sequential key.

> DEBUG IdentifierGeneratorHelper - Natively generated identity: 0

I have verified in sql server, AFIS_Sequence is generating sequence each and every time. That means there is some issues with hibernate configuration.

Is there any configuration missed or is it a bug of hibernate ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`CustomSQLDialect` should extend `SQLServer2012Dialect`, as previous versions didn't support sequences.

Answer (score 4):

When you use

```
@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
```

You are using the auto increment that have hibernate, but if you use

```
@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
```

You will use the auto increment of your data base

Answer (score 1):

According to Hibernate 4.x documentation we have:

> GeneratorType.AUTO
>   This is the default strategy and is portable across different databases. Hibernate
>   chooses the appropriate ID based on the database.

For the `GeneratorType.AUTO` your table must have an `Auto Incremented Primary Key`.

We have also:

> GeneratorType.SEQUENCE
>   Some databases provide a mechanism of sequenced numbers, so this setting will let
>   Hibernate use the sequence number.

What I can see is that you didn't specify correctly which sequente Hibernate should use, follow this example:

```
public class Employee {
@Id
@Column(name="EMPLOYEE_ID")
@GeneratedValue (strategy= GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator="empSeqGen")
@SequenceGenerator(name = "empSeqGen", sequenceName = "EMP_SEQ_GEN")
private int employeeId =0;
...
}
```

You need to create a Sequence in your Database and specify it to your bean.

Edit:

I am adding more information:

> The strategy is defined as a SEQUENCE, and accordingly the generator is given a reference
>   to a sequence generator, empSeqGen, which refers to a sequence object in the database.
>   Using the @SequenceGenerator, we reference EMP_SEQ_GEN, which is a sequence object
>   created in the database.

Comment: I have created `AFIS_Sequence` in database. Do I need to create a bean named `empSeqGen` ?

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)`.

But I recomment to understand what each one do:

- **AUTO**: Indicates that the persistence provider should pick an
  appropriate strategy for the particular database.
- **IDENTITY**: Indicates that the persistence provider must assign primary
  keys for the entity using a database identity column.
- **SEQUENCE**: Indicates that the persistence provider must assign primary
  keys for the entity using a database sequence.
- **TABLE**: Indicates that the persistence provider must assign primary
  keys for the entity using an underlying database table to ensure
  uniqueness.

For more information please visit the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/GenerationType.html).

Answer (score -1):

```
import java.util.Date;
import javax.persistence.*;

@Entity
@Table(name="driver_license")
public class DriverLicense extends License {
private String driverLicenseName;
 @Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
 private Date driverLicenseExpiryDate;
 @Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
 private Date driverLicenseIssueDate;


public String getDriverLicenseName() {
    return driverLicenseName;
}
public void setDriverLicenseName(String driverLicenseName) {
    this.driverLicenseName = driverLicenseName;
}
public Date getDriverLicenseExpiryDate() {
    return driverLicenseExpiryDate;
}
public void setDriverLicenseExpiryDate(Date driverLicenseExpiryDate) {
    this.driverLicenseExpiryDate = driverLicenseExpiryDate;
}
public Date getDriverLicenseIssueDate() {
    return driverLicenseIssueDate;
}
public void setDriverLicenseIssueDate(Date driverLicenseIssueDate) {
    this.driverLicenseIssueDate = driverLicenseIssueDate;
}
}


import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.MappedSuperclass;
import javax.persistence.SequenceGenerator;

@MappedSuperclass
public class License {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.SEQUENCE,generator="license_gen")
@SequenceGenerator(name="license_gen",sequenceName="lic_seq_gen",initialValue=1,allocationSize=1)
protected int id;

public int getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(int id) {
    this.id = id;
}
}


import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.hibernate.boot.registry.StandardServiceRegistryBuilder;
import org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration;

public class HibernateUtil {

private static SessionFactory sessionFactory ;
static{
    Configuration configuration=new Configuration();
     configuration.addAnnotatedClass(DriverLicense.class);
    // configuration.addAnnotatedClass(DriverLicense.class);
    configuration.setProperty("connection.driver_class","org.postgresql.Driver");
    configuration.setProperty("hibernate.connection.url", "jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/test");                                
    configuration.setProperty("hibernate.connection.username", "postgres");     
    configuration.setProperty("hibernate.connection.password", "postgres");
    configuration.setProperty("dialect", "org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect");
    configuration.setProperty("hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto", "update");
    configuration.setProperty("hibernate.show_sql", "true");
    configuration.setProperty(" hibernate.connection.pool_size", "10");


    StandardServiceRegistryBuilder registry=new StandardServiceRegistryBuilder().applySettings(configuration.getProperties());
    sessionFactory=configuration.buildSessionFactory(registry.build());

}

 public static SessionFactory getSessionFactory() {
        return sessionFactory;
    }
}



public class Main {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    DriverLicense driverLicense=new DriverLicense();

    driverLicense.setDriverLicenseExpiryDate(new Date());
    driverLicense.setDriverLicenseName("License for all");
    driverLicense.setDriverLicenseIssueDate(new Date());

    Session session=HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession();

    try {
        session.beginTransaction();

        session.save(driverLicense);

        session.getTransaction().commit();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
}
```